# Can I do a PCR test to avoid quarantine in Minsk, Belarus?

Tags: air-travel, europe, covid-19, belarus, quarantine

I need to travel to Minsk, Belarus from Berlin, Germany for a couple of days. I'm flying with Belavia and on their website, it says that all inbound passengers have to quarantine for 10 days. I was wondering if it's possible to do a PCR test once I land in Minsk and show a negative result in order to avoid the quarantine. However, I couldn't find any related information.

For example, if you fly into Berlin you have to quarantine or you can also do a PCR test and show a negative result which would allow you to avoid quarantining for 10 days. I'm hoping their is something similar in Minsk.

Comment: I think you got the Berlin details wrong: Since November you have to do a minimum of 5 days of quarantine and only then can take a test to get out. See https://www.berlin.de/corona/massnahmen/einreisen/#:~:text=Die%20Quarant%C3%A4ne%20kann%20fr%C3%BChestens%20f%C3%BCnf,nach%20der%20Einreise%20durchgef%C3%BChrt%20wurde.

Comment: @Hilmar Thanks for the update! My information is from August/September because when I came back to Berlin, I did the test directly at the airport and only had to quarantine while waiting for the results.

Answer (score 1):

[Apparently](https://www.officeholidays.com/coronavirus/belarus), Germany is - [together with the USA and others](https://by.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/covid-19-information/) - one of the countries whose citizens can enter Belarus without being quarantined, as of July 2020. Here it is [another website](https://airport.by/en/priletausim/Prevention) with also a local number of an info-line.